# Why `filetype on` doesn't detect file type in vim?

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04

I opened `vim` without loading anything:

```
vim -V -u NONE
```

And typed one line:

```
<?xml?>
```

After running:

```
:unlet did_load_filetypes
:filetype on
```

I check the file type of current buffer:

```
:set ft?
```

It print `filetype=`

---

If I type

```
:unlet did_load_filetypes
:filetype detect
```

then `:set ft?` will print `filetype=xml`.

---

In the vim doc:

```
Detail: The ":filetype on" command will load one of these files:                                    
                Amiga       $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim                                                
                Mac         $VIMRUNTIME:filetype.vim                                                
                MS-DOS      $VIMRUNTIME\filetype.vim                                                
                RiscOS      Vim:Filetype                                                            
                Unix        $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim                                                
                VMS         $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim                                                
        This file is a Vim script that defines autocommands for the                                 
        BufNewFile and BufRead events.  If the file type is not found by the                        
        name, the file $VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim is used to detect it from the                        
        contents of the file.
```

---

What's differences between `:filetype on` and `:filetype detect`?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual:

```
To detect the file type again:
    :filetype detect
Use this if you started with an empty file and typed text that makes it
possible to detect the file type.
```

Answer (score 1):

`$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` only defines autocommands for the `BufNewFile` and `BufRead` events.

After running the `:filetype on` command, none of the events get trigged, so nothing happed. To trigge the event, you can save it with `:w filename`, and reopen it with `:e!`

I guess, `:filetype detect` runs some code to trigger the `BufNewFile` or `BufRead` events.